# How do I change the text directly beneath the icon of my iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

There is small text beneath the icon names when you are in the home screen of the ipod.

My text is much too long and it looks like `"Cedr..egg"`

I was wondering if there was a way to change that text to a shorter name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `Bundle Display Name` in the `info.plist` file.

Comment: winner winner chicken dinner... thank you very much this is exactly it

Comment: Then you should give him an upvote.  That way you'll get more questions answered in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name of the app by renaming the app in the Applications folder in iTunes.

If you are looking to do this in Xcode you are looking for the LocalizedApplicationNames.strings file.

NOTE: This may prevent automatic upgrades in the future.

Comment: I am making the app that I want to change the name for... so will it effect automatic upgrades for the user???